# How to convert complex double for loop to Java 8 Streams reduce complexity and improve performance

Tags: java, performance, functional-programming, stream

I'm trying to rewrite this complex double for loop which seems to be a bit expensive, I think rewriting this using streams would improve readability and perhaps even avoid unnecessary looping iterations.

I'd like to convert this imperative code here:

```
public Documents clearDocuments(List<Document> toDeleteDocs) {
    Documents softDeleteList = new Documents();
    List<EntityKeyVersion> deleteList = entityManager.bulkDeleteEntities(ekList,EntityClient.DeleteMode.SOFT_DELETE);
    for (Document doc : toDeleteDocs) {
        for (EntityKeyVersion ekv : deleteList) {
            if (ekv.getEntityKey().contentEquals(doc.getEntityKey())) {
                doc.setVersion((ekv.getEntityVersion()));
                softDeleteList.getDocument().add(doc);
            } else if (softDeleteList.getDocument().size() == deleteList.size()) {
                break; // once soft delete list is fully populated, break out of loop to save unnecessary iterations
            }
        }
    }
    return softDeleteList;
}
```

to make use of the java 8 streams,

this is what I tried so far, I think I have the double loops down but the inner conditions as filters might be wrong seems I'm missing quite a bit:

```
Documents softDeleteList = new Documents();
List<EntityKeyVersion> deleteList = entityManager.bulkDeleteEntities(ekList,EntityClient.DeleteMode.SOFT_DELETE);

return softDeleteList.getDocument().stream()
        .filter(doc -> deleteList.stream()
                        .peek(jh -> )
                        .anyMatch(ekv -> ekv.getEntityKey().contentEquals(doc.getEntityKey())))
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Any help or assistance would be much appreciated, thanks in advance

Comment: Streams often hurt, not help, for complex loops.  Streams are mostly only good for simplifying simple loops.  This looks like a case where streams may not help.

Comment: I think of streams as a sort of pipeline or factory processing objects. It seems to me this might be a good candidate for a stream so as to remove any unnecessary iterations (of course internally there will be iterations). My attempt above might have been not the best one as it does indeed look complicated but I am certain there is a far better approach

Comment: *"I think rewriting this using streams would improve readability and perhaps even avoid unnecessary looping iterations."* --- You're wrong, converting to streams will not improve readability, and it certainly won't avoid unnecessary looping. If you want to improve the code, especially to improve the performance by not having nested loops doing sequential searches, convert the `deleteList` into a `Set` or `Map`, so you can do direct lookups.

Comment: "You're wrong, converting to streams will not improve readability" is this a fact ? :) 

"convert the deleteList into a `Set` or `Map`, so you can do direct lookups" - thank you, why didn't I think of this before. I will try this, much appreiated